# How to avoid ugly imports in TS Triple-Slash Directives

Tags: typescript, types

I have a nested order structure. If I now used the triple slash directives, I have a long data path depending on the file like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../global.d.ts" />
```

The question I'm asking myself now is there a way to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [TypeScript 1.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-1-5/) (see section *"Lightweight, portable projects"*), the syntax `/// <reference` is replaced by a [configuration file *tsconfig.json*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

An example for Node.js:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

In the `tsconfig.json` file, `include` and `exclude` properties can be defined. When an `exclude` property is defined, then all the rest is by default included. Now your project could look like:

```
- project-directory/
    |- dist/
    |- node_modules/
    |- src/
        |- global.d.ts
        |- path/to/other/files.ts
    |- tsconfig.json
```

Comment: ok so in the tsconfig.json I can... include the global.d.ts? Can you give me an example with the global.d.ts? Should it be in the path object?

Comment: @Ckappo I edited. If you exclude something, all the rest will be included. You can put `global.d.ts` in the project root directory or in any non-excluded sub-directory.

Comment: Ty Paleo. Works like I want